# Spring boot H2 database application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I have created a sample project with following code. Even if i am not providing table create statement in the data.sql, it is creating the table. how to stop that. Sample code is present below

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? I have removed the import statements below as the post was not allowing to put so much code here.

```
package com.example.demo;
// Model class 
@Entity
@Table(name="reservation")
public class Reservation {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 @Column(name="user_id")
 private Long userId;    
 @Column(name="party_size")
 private int partySize;
 @Column(name="restaurant_id")
 private Long restaurantId;
 @Column(name="date")
 private LocalDateTime dt;
 public Reservation() {}
 public Reservation(Long id,  Long userId, int partySize) {
  this.id = id;
  this.userId = userId;
  this.partySize = partySize;
 }
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public Long getUserId() {
  return userId;
 }
 public void setUserId(Long userId) {
  this.userId = userId;
 }
 public int getPartySize() {
  return partySize;
 }
 public void setPartySize(int partySize) {
  this.partySize = partySize;
 }
  public Long getRestaurantId() {
  return restaurantId;
 }
 public void setRestaurantId(Long restaurantId) {
  this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
 }
 public LocalDateTime getDt() {
  return dt;
 }
 public void setDt(LocalDateTime dt) {
  this.dt = dt;
 }
}

package com.example.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationApp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ReservationApp.class, args);
 }
}

package com.example.demo;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class ReservationController {

 @Autowired
 private ReservationService reservationService;

 // ------------ Retrieve all reservations ------------
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reservations", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List getAllReservations() {

  return reservationService.getAllReservations();

 }

package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface ReservationRepository extends CrudRepository<Reservation,String> {
 }

 package com.example.demo;

@Service 
public class ReservationService {

 @Autowired
 private ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

 // Retrieve all rows from table and populate list with objects
 public List getAllReservations() {
  List reservations = new ArrayList<>();
  reservationRepository.findAll().forEach(reservations::add);
  return reservations;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Is it creating the table every-time you start your app ? If so, then it's normal becasue it's H2 db

Comment: But I don't want them to create them and I want to put create statement for this.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the spring boot hibernate configuration

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Which is able of creating/updating the database schema from entities

Comment: sorry. I don't follow this question. what is multiple profile. another question where is hibernate.configuration file present. I have changed application.property to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none. but I think its not right place

Comment: you have a file called application.properties inside the resources folder thats it. you have only one. properties file, then you have no profiles

Comment: you can create multiple profiles one profile for each environment. for example you can use one orofile for development and other for production and every one of them has its .properties files

Comment: it's application.properties not application.property

Answer (score 0):

To disable automatic DDL generation, set the following property to `false` in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = false
```

For more information and fine-grained control, please see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set the ddl generation to none in the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```